# enqueued jQuery issue after WooCommerce installation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently installed WooCommerce with my own theme but for some reason I am getting errors with jQuery. I can only think it is WooCommerce as I have never had an issue before.

I normally call jQuery in the footer with the code:

```
function web_scripts(){

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', '', '1.11.3', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'web_scripts' );
```

But since installing WooCommerce (never used WooCommerce before) my jQuery doesn't appear in the footer and I get a console error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

However when I make jQuery appear in the header I don't get the console errors but instead I get:

```
"/*"

[CDATA[ */
var wc_add_to_cart_params = {"ajax_url":"\/hagleystoves\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","wc_ajax_url":"\/hagleystoves\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%","i18n_view_cart":"View Cart","cart_url":"http:\/\/192.168.1.205\/hagleystoves\/cart\/","is_cart":"","cart_redirect_after_add":"no"};
/* ]]

"*/"
```

This code displays as /**/ at the bottom of the page. I am really unsure how resolve this as I have never had this issue with my theme before until installing WooCommerce.

Any help with this would be really appreciated. Thanks to everyone who has taken the time to read this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your theme or plugin file. Try using this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_basic');

function wptuts_scripts_basic() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I already put my enqueue codes in a function and add action. 

I have tried your suggestion but it still loads jquery within the header and I get the WooCommerce CDATA error.